# Auto 'Y' answer for gpg --delete-secret-key

Tags: gnupg

Please, can any one tell me, how i can delete the gpg keys without being prompt from console.

I tried "printf "y\ny\n" | gpg --delete-secret-key test"
and "echo -e "y\ny\n" | gpg --delete-secret-key test " but in vain.

Thanks,

Fadel

Comment: Have you tried `yes | gpg --delete-secret-key test`?

Comment: yes, but i didn t work.

Comment: Try `gpg –batch -yes --delete-secret-key test`. This should do it.

Comment: @alvits It should be gpg `--batch --yes --delete-secret-key test`